# How can I play the video using my app

Tags: android, android-video-player

How can I enable user to play the video using my app.
In my code when I open the video player, all the videos are coming in a list view and by clicking on any video, it will start playing on second activity.
Now I want to enable that when ever the user wants to play a video from their phone, it should also play through my app.
Below code in manifest help me in taking to the my video player in first activity but I  want that It should start playing Video Immediately after selecting my video player.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your intent filter in the activity that you want to launch for it.

For example :

```
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="VideoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
             ... (your intent-filters here)
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This will make `MainActivity` the one that is launched when the user starts your app directly, and `VideoActivity` will start when you choose it when selecting a video to play.

Comment: I have done exactly this but the problem is that it is not playing the video when we select from from our device or gallery, it is showing error. But when I put intent filters in second activity then is going to the my video player but not playing the video

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you use `getData()` to get URI for the content to be played? (link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW )